# Getting a list of users by grepping /etc/passwd

Tags: text-processing, grep, users

For a homework assignment, I need to use `grep` to parse `/etc/passwd` and get a list of all users (their usernames only, nothing else). It should use a pipe, and the results should end up in the `allusers` file. This is what I have so far:

```
grep -i etc/password | .... >allusers
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That `grep` looks for patterns and normally prints out the whole line, you need to limit its output to _just_ the match. Check the manpage.

Answer (score 11):

#### Hint

Each field in a `/etc/passwd` line is separated by a colon, and the username is the first field, so you need to filter each line to only show the characters up to the first colon

#### Answer

`grep` is not even close to the best tool for doing this, but if you're required to use it, this will work:

```
grep -oE '^[^:]+' /etc/passwd
```

`-o` tells it to only return the part of the line that matches. `-E` turns on extended regular expressions so the `+` will work later. `^` matches the beginning of the line, `[^:]` matches anything except a colon, and `+` means as many characters as possible. So this will match the beginning of every line up until the first colon

If you're able to use other tools besides `grep`, here are other generally better ways of doing it:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
sed 's/:.*//' /etc/passwd
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

You can redirect the results from any of those into `allusers` using `> allusers` like you have in your example

Comment: [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65263/getting-a-list-of-users-by-grepping-etc-passwd#65266) _italic_ **bold** `Thank you so much for answering my question. However, is there anyway that I can use pipe in this command?'

Comment: @guest12 There's no need for one, but `grep` can read stdin instead of a file, so you could do `cat /etc/passwd | grep -oE '^[^:]+'` instead I suppose

Comment: Re @MichaelMrozek's comment, you could throw in a `sort(1)` to get them in alphabetical order. Useless Use of Cat, or [UUC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) is considered bad taste in Unixland.

Comment: While this is correct and a good answer, I wouldn't have gone beyond hints, since this was OP's homework

Answer (score 0):

Grep is not suitable for this situation, try to get the password file with `getent` and parse it with awk (colon separated content),

`getent passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' > allusers`

Answer (score 0):

`cat /etc/passwd | awk -F : '{print $1}' > alluser.txt`

Comment: `cat | awk` ? Wow, impressive :/

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o '^[a-zA-Z]*:' /etc/passwd
```

works for me..it only prints the user names whose names begins with `a-zA-Z`  ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
grep -E 1[0-9]{3}  /etc/passwd | sed s/:/\ / | awk '{print $1}'
```

Just to get non-system or builtin users.